# What does pg_stat_all_tables.idx_scan actually mean?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.5

We have a busy PostgreSQL 9.5 server with OLTP-like traffic where `pg_stat_all_tables.idx_scan` values go up with considerate rate while we're having performance problems.

Does that (`idx_scan` increasing) actually mean that

1. the system is actually running lots of full scans through indexes (meaning, reading the whole index from the disk if not already in the cache), or
2. the system is actually getting some only some tuples ("rows") from those indexes (that is, using the index as intended)?

**If the option 1 is true, how to figure out how to get system into state 2?** Do I need some additional indexes or are some of my queries bad? All queries get nice performance while the system is under low load but during very high load pretty much any query can get unexpectedly poor execution time.

(The documentation at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html only says "Number of index scans initiated on this table".)

Comment: When the system is under heavy load, does that load come from a massive number of queries or from DML statements?

Comment: Mostly from massive number of queries. I think around 1-3% of DML statements.

Comment: We're seeing some single field on single row updates taking very long time (something like it normally takes less than 0.1 ms and under heavy load randomly taking 20000+ ms).

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out if the SSD RAID is being overwhelmed by the IO or if there's some kind of logical problem.

Comment: Massive numbers of queries makes me think of a website, not an OLTP system with a limited number of users in-house.  Where do these queries originate from?

Comment: Majority of the traffic comes through a website but nearly all transactions have isolation SERIALIZED and all SERIALIZED transactions are short (usually way less than 100 ms) which I think is closer to usual OLTP load.

Comment: At least this definition of OLTP matches our traffic pretty well: https://database.guide/what-is-oltp/ (except that we're also reading lots of data in addition - is this what you mean)?

Comment: Can you check with the people responsible for the website if there is a problem with caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever an index is used, that counts as an index scan.  There is no separate counter for full index scans.  You could compare idx_scan to
idx_tup_fetch and see how any rows are returned from the index per scan on average.  But what is the point?  For the most part, it fetches the number of rows it needs to in order to do the job you assigned it.  Maybe you are missing an index that could do the job better, but looking at this stat will not tell that that is the case, nor tell you what hypothetical index that might be.

I do a lot of performance investigation and almost never look at those values, unless I'm trying to tune/debug autovac.  `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, `pg_stat_statements`, `auto_explain` are the right tools for the job.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I think I'll keep monitoring `idx_tup_fetch` instead to get overall image on index usage. I believe that we are exceeding the available IO performance with the current storage devices and new hardware is already on its way.

Comment: By the way, how about `seq_scan`? Is it possible to do partial sequential scan or does that always refer to scanning through whole table? Considering how `idx_scan` works I would guess that if I use `LIMIT` in query the `seq_scan` would be increased even if only LIMIT rows were read.

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY is the only thing I can think of that would do a partial seq scan.  Experimentally, it does cause seq_scan to increment.

Comment: *Year 2022 summary:* `seq_scan` and `idx_scan` are basically query counters which just report if the query hit index or the whole table at all. If you have any idea about the total query count otherwise, you can ignore those. The `idx_tup_fetch` and `seq_tup_read` are the counters you want to use and tell you *how much* data was actually read from the index or actual data table. You should have sensible number of tuples fetch for each query and if you see too high tuple fetch counts it means you have poor queries or missing indexes. See also: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/226481/29183